# undefined reference when linking static library

Tags: c++

I have following files and codes:

test.hpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "utils.hpp"

class test
{
public:
    void func();

    template<typename T>
    void tfunc(T t);
};

template<typename T>
void test::tfunc(T t)
{
    std::cout << "tfunc(): " << t << std::endl;
    utils::ufunc();
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "utils.hpp"
#include "test.hpp"

void test::func()
{
    std::cout << "func" << std::endl;
    utils::ufunc();
}
```

utils.hpp:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace utils
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

void ufunc();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
}
```

utils.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "utils.hpp"

using namespace utils;

void ufunc()
{
    std::cout << "ufunc" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"

int main()
{
    test t;

    t.func();
    t.tfunc(10);
}
```

I used following commands to compile and generate lib from test.cpp and utils.cpp:

```
g++ -c test.cpp utils.cpp
ar -cvq test.a test.o utils.o
```

Then, I built main.cpp and tried to link it:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ main.o test.a
```

But, I'm getting link error: undefined reference to `ufunc'

I added extern "C" to utils.hpp, but still getting link error. Tried to search the same problem in stackoverflow, but could not find.

Comment: Missed `utils::` here `void ufunc()` in utils.cpp.

Comment: Unrelated: No point to the `extern "C"` shuffle. C will choke as soon as the parser hits `namespace`.

Comment: @user4581301 The `extern "C"` part is fine, but the `ifdef __cplusplus` parts are useless because of that.

Comment: Shouldn't the ufunc() definition be in a namespace or namespace :: qualified in utils.cpp?

Comment: @DanielH the point is C can't parse the header, so why bother trying to make part of it parsible? Much more work is needed. The conditional compilation must enclose all of the C++-only stuff.

Answer (score 2):

When you define `void ufunc()` in utils.cpp, you are defining it in the global namespace.

You should define it as `void utils::ufunc()`, otherwise, the `void utils::ufunc()` you declared in utils.hpp is never being defined.

Comment: good catch! That's the place that took my time today. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of your namespace. You can use `nm -C` to see what symbols are present in object (.o) and library (.a) files. Do that, and see whether you have `ufunc` or `utils::ufunc`.